# Spotify iOS SDK Beta 25 no sound on real device

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, spotify

Spotify's iOS Beta 25 SDK
Xcode Version 8.3.2 (8E2002)
iPhone 6s Plus 10.3.1

Everything works properly with the iPhone simulator. No sound plays on my real device, but all the SPTAudioStreamingPlaybackDelegates fire properly.

I've tried multiple real devices, and they work perfectly. My iPhone 6s Plus will play sound with headphones, but not without headphones. But all the delagates are fireing. So its as if it's muted without headphones.

```
func audioStreaming(_ audioStreaming: SPTAudioStreamingController!, didStartPlayingTrack trackUri: String!) {

    print("This works: didStartPlayingTrack")

}

func audioStreaming(_ audioStreaming: SPTAudioStreamingController!, didChangePlaybackStatus isPlaying: Bool) {

    print("This works: didChangePlaybackStatus")

}

func audioStreaming(_ audioStreaming: SPTAudioStreamingController!, didSeekToPosition position: TimeInterval) {

    print("This works: didSeekToPosition")

}
```

It seems as if the sound is just muted on my real device.

I also have the same issue when using this barebones demo:
https://github.com/elonrubin/Spotify-SDK-Swift-Tutorial-Part-One

Has anyone encountered this?

Comment: There are many reasons this might occur, have you checked that the track you are playing is playable in your country?

Comment: I've tried many things. It's hard to provide all the details. But the tracks I've tried are definitely playable. It actually works fine on other real devices. My iPhone 6s Plus only works with headphones in. No sound without headphones. But the actual spotify and music app sound works fine without headphones, so it doesn't seem to be a problem with the device.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so it has to do with the silent mode switch being on silent. I have never encountered this issue before. Does anyone know if this is a new thing?

I had to add this:

```
do {
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback, with: AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions.mixWithOthers)

            do {
                try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)

            } catch let error as NSError {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
```